# C++ monitoring key presses in Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos

I'm new to programming in C++ and Mac. Currently trying to set up a little console game of snake or something as a learning exercise.

Right now I can't figure out how to monitor for key presses. In Windows in similar exercises I've used `GetAsyncKeyState`. I'm not sure what the Mac equivalent is? I see a lot written about `ncurses.h` or `Carbon/Carbon.h` but all my attempts with these have failed.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me implement this, or else point me in the direction of some well explained step-by-step guide for monitoring key presses.

The below is kind of the skeleton program I have got to so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h> //need this for the time stuff

using namespace std;  

long fnMilliSecs()
{
//returns milliseconds that day as long
    timeval time; //declares var
    long millis;

    gettimeofday(&time, NULL); //this gets time
    millis = (time.tv_sec * 1000) + (time.tv_usec / 1000);
    return millis;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    long lngMilliSecondsNow;

    cout << "1\n";
    cout << "2\n";

    //system pause    
    lngMilliSecondsNow = fnMilliSecs();

    //wait for 5 secs while monitoring for key press
    do
    {

    //if a certain key is pressed, do something like print it to console 

    ### NEED TO FIGURE OUT THIS SECTION ###

    } while (fnMilliSecs() < lngMilliSecondsNow + 5000);

    cout << "3\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ncurses is really the way to go for more advanced text-based applications like yours. Start with the most simple "hello world" tutorial and continue (in small baby-steps) from there. If you have trouble with your ncurses application then please post a question about that, and we'll be able to better help you.